# Google Apps Script: GA02

Tags: email

Let me start by saying that I do not speak programming so please answer my question as though you’re talking to a young child, or a dog, or even an alien.

I receive an email every day with the subject “summary of failures for Google Apps Script: GA02.  The error message is that “authorization is required to perform that action”.  I have clicked on the hyperlink to chamber the setting for receiving notifications or to “configure triggers” and don’t see any obvious way to find what this script is.  It says the script is used by the document [Addon] GA02 Save Emails.  When I click on the hyperlink to access the script, I get a pop up saying I don’t have permission - so I request permission but have no idea who I’m asking permission from.  I only have one Google account.  My daughter has two accounts but she’s not receiving this request.  I’d love to fix the error.  I realize I can just block the sender but then some script is running somewhere that doesn’t need to be.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Clicking on unsolicited emails links is not a good idea. Probably worth having someone check your computer

Comment: Please go to https://script.google.com/home/triggers and remove any triggers that may be creating these notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help resolve your issue. [Summary of failures for Google Apps Script - Troubleshoot](https://www.labnol.org/failure-email-4488)

It details "How to Stop Failure Emails from Google Script" and "How to Delete Inactive Triggers in Google Scripts (403)"